# What did I just do with the trackpad to make my window take up half the desktop?

Tags: macos, trackpad, shortcut, desktop

I was just clicking with the trackpad - I wasn't doing anything else, and my fingers moved a little and somehow my Google Chrome window took up the left half of the screen.

What did I do here?

Comment: What you may have done is [enabled split view](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948).

Comment: @TMHahn no, that definitely wasn't it (though looks like a useful shortcut). It was as if I grabbed the right hand side of the window and pulled it right to the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the maximize button of the window and drag it to one side of the screen.

Comment: That's what Frysk suggested, but no, that wasn't it. I may have clicked on the left edge of the screen, but it wasn't a precise enough hit for that, also, different behavior.